# TypeError: mongodb property insertmany is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
db.col.insertMany(
    [
        {
        "_id" : "tt0084726",
        "title" : "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan",
        "year" : 1982,
        "type" : "movie"
        },
        {
        "_id" : "tt0796366",
        "title" : "Star Trek",
        "year" : 2009,
        "type" : "movie"
        },
        {
        "_id" : "tt0084726",
        "title" : "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan",
        "year" : 1982,
        "type" : "movie"
        }
    ]
);
```

> OS: LinuxMint 17.3 Rosa MongoDB: db version v2.6.12

I am participating in a course by the [University of MongoDB](https://university.mongodb.com). When I input the command as above into mongo shell, an Error occurs: `TypeError: Property 'insertMany' of object test.col is not a function`
how to solve it? I have read the docs but still failed.

Comment: what version of mongo are you using ?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12

Comment: please use that link you can find the detail : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68662249/10936485

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem. You need to have version 3.2

[> New in version 3.2.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)

You need to update your version of mongodb to use `insertMany`.

It's not so hard. I did it a couple weeks ago to use `insertMany`

Answer (score 7):

I am newbie in `MongoDB` , I got similar error in another scenario. I am adding that also an answer here, any future reader may find useful!

`db.users.insertMany (`**[**`{name:"Ajith",status:"pending",age:25}, {name:"Kumar",status:"withheld",age:40}, {name:"Lal",status:"passed",age:34}, {name:"Tishil Joppen",status:"high",age:28}`**]**`)`

I forgot to include the square brackets , and got the same error!!

Answer (score 0):

since your Mongo version is MongoDB: db version v2.6.12 (< 3.2) you need to run

```
db.col.insert(
[
    {
    "_id" : "tt0084726",
    "title" : "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan",
    "year" : 1982,
    "type" : "movie"
    },
    {
    "_id" : "tt0796366",
    "title" : "Star Trek",
    "year" : 2009,
    "type" : "movie"
    },
    {
    "_id" : "tt0084726",
    "title" : "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan",
    "year" : 1982,
    "type" : "movie"
    }
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Ensure your table name is plural:

db.cols.insertMany