# Mongodb/mongoose insert is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My insert is not working, I got error of Error :

> Token.insert is not a function

```
var Token = module.exports = mongoose.model('tokens', tokenSchema);

//error
module.exports.saveToken = function(owner_id, token, callback){
    console.log(owner_id,token);
    Token.insert({"owner":owner_id,"token":token},callback);
}
//working
module.exports.getAllTokens = function(owner_id, callback){
    Token.find({"owner":owner_id},callback);
}
```

Comment: is `Token` defined in this file ? How is it passed to it

Comment: @MukeshSharma updated my question

Comment: please add tokenSchema definition, and type exact problem. You're saying: Token.insert is not a function. We - help You fix it, but after I get that You need to insert token into token array. So please fix Your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code example, it should work as You need.

I don's see here any non-understanding part.

Ask questions in comments, I can explain if don't understand.

```
var tokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  owner: { 
    type: 'String',
    required: true,
    index: {
      unique: true
    }
  }, 
  token: {
    type: ['String'],
    default: []
  }
});

var Token = module.exports = mongoose.model('tokens', tokenSchema);

//save token, if token document exist so push it in token array and save
module.exports.saveToken = function(owner_id, token, callback){
    Token
      .findOne({owner: owner_id})
      .exec(function(err, tokenDocument) {
        if(tokenDocument) {
          if(tokenDocument.token.indexOf(token) > -1) { // found that token already exist in document token array
            return callback(null, tokenDocument); // don't do anything and return to callback existing tokenDocument
          }

          tokenDocument.token.push(token);
          tokenDocument.save(callback);
          return; // don't go down, cuz we already have a token document
        }

        new Token({owner: owner_id, token: [token]}).save(callback); // create new token document with single token in token array
    });
}

//get all tokens by owner_id
module.exports.getAllTokens = function(owner_id, callback){
    Token
      .findOne({owner: owner_id})
      .exec(function(err, tokenDocument) {
        callback(err, tokenDocument.token);
      });
}
```

Comment: this won't work, forgot to mention my schema the token is an array. Like this `var tokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "owner" : {
     type:String
    },
    "token" : []
});`

Comment: You've not mentioned about schema anywhere. Check out new changes in my answer

Comment: The issue is it will still create another set of insert if the owner is the same. How to do if the owner is the same just push the token, not duplicate the entire document?

Comment: checkout "better solution", it gets Token by owner if it exists and pushes new token and saves it. otherwise creates new record with single token in it.

Comment: what does return do in findOne callback?

Comment: findOne is mongoose function, that get one record with first occurrence of owner and returns err, result (the token instance)

Comment: it will not ensure the array is unquie.

Comment: I've added tokenDocument.token.indexOf(token) checking that will not allow inserting duplicate

Comment: tried, it doesn't solved the problem, still the array isn't unquie.

Comment: @AliciaBrandon what You mean isn't unique? what is not unique? token array? or document itself? What about just delete document of the user and try again with normal document?

Comment: tq so much for ur help number!

Comment: ohh (: at last! happy that I was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
let newvalue = new Token({"owner":owner_id,"token":token});
newvalue.save();
```

Comment: `save` versus insert verus create what is the different?

Comment: it's dumb that Mongoose does not have an insert API, because that's the native API, I guess `Model.create()` takes the place of `Model.insert()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here i defined what is the problem that why they did not find the **insertMany**

generally, we create an instance to save a document in DB like this :

```
const instance = new Model(data);
```

After then we hit the save query

```
instance.save(data).then().catch()
```

But when we talk about the **insertMany** Section, **No need to create any instance**. you can insert all entries directly via **Model**

eg.

```
Modal.insertMany(data).then().catch()
```