# insertMany is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For my project I am making a system that lets users create and configure their own soccer tournaments. After a tournament is made I have to put poules and teams into the tournament document in mongo. I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: toernooi.insertMany is not a function
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodeprojects\contactlistapp\server.js:254:13
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodeprojects\contactlistapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3398:16)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodeprojects\contactlistapp\node_modules\kareem\index.js:259:21
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodeprojects\contactlistapp\node_modules\kareem\index.js:127:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

I'm trying to insert an array into an existing document in mongodb with the following code:

```
app.put('/poules/:id', function(req,res){
//Select Toernooi object in DB by ID
Toernooi.findById(req.params.id, function(err, toernooi){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);

    toernooi.poules = {
        poule : {
            team: { teamnaam: 'psv', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            team: { teamnaam: 'ajax', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            team: { teamnaam: 'feyenoord', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0'  },
            team: { teamnaam: 'ado', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' }
        },
        poule : {
            team: { teamnaam: 'vitesse', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            team: { teamnaam: 'achilles', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            team: { teamnaam: 'jvc', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            team: { teamnaam: 'twente', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' }
        }
    };              

    toernooi.insertMany(toernooi.poules, function(error, docs));
});
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong, since I am new to NodeJS and Mongo I figured i might be doing something simple very wrong.

Mongoose version : 4.7
MongoDB version : 3.2.10

Comment: Your `toernooi.poules` declaration isn't valid syntax. Objects can't have multiple properties with the same key. You probably need arrays, instead.

Comment: please use that link you can find the detail : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697448/mongodb-mongoose-insert-is-not-a-function/68662249#68662249

Answer (score 2):

In the example you gave, `toernooi` is the result of your top query. A result has no insertMany function, only the model `Toernooi`.

in any case, what you're doing here is a simple update of a document, so the following should work :

```
app.put('/poules/:id', function(req,res){

//Select Toernooi object in DB by ID

Toernooi.findById(req.params.id, function(err, toernooi){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);

    toernooi.poules = [
        [
            { teamnaam: 'psv', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            { teamnaam: 'ajax', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            { teamnaam: 'feyenoord', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0'  },
            { teamnaam: 'ado', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' }
        ],[
            { teamnaam: 'vitesse', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            { teamnaam: 'achilles', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            { teamnaam: 'jvc', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' },
            { teamnaam: 'twente', pt: '0', dptplus: '0', dptminus: '0' }
        ]
    ];              

    toernooi.save(function(err,res){

    });
});
```

Edit : As mentioned in comments, your syntax was invalid for poules. here it is as an array.

Comment: Why don't you use an array of poules? Don't number them like that.

Comment: thinking of queries later down the line, tournaments usually have a fixed number of poules, etc. basically, just overthinking it!

Comment: Much better now :D

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, This code does work however now i've got an poules array with an object in mongo with only an ID, it doesn't show the teams or poules. I think I'm misunderstanding some things

Comment: check your model, make sure it reflects the changes you want to make to your structure. the 'array of arrays' is probably not the best design, but at least now you know how to `.save()` your changes! :)

Comment: If I log toernooi.poules with your code i get the following: [ { poule: [], _id: 583ebe2eb11c93c70ccf81f3 }, { poule: [], _id: 583ebe2eb11c93c70ccf81f2 } ] , it seems like poule [] is empty

Comment: You are right, I think i found the problem :P I'll accept your answer as soon as i figured it out, Thanks!!