# InsertMany not working in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm fairly new to Mongoose and MongoDB itself and I'm trying to save a bunch of documents inserted via insertMany method but it is not saving the docs.

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var hostSchema = new Schema({
    hostname: String,
    timestamp: Number,

});

var hostModel = mongoose.model('host', hostSchema, 'host');

module.exports = hostModel;
```

**ExpressJS Post route**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var hostModel = require('../../models/Host');

router.post('/host', function (req, res, next) {
    var payload = req.body;

    (async function(){
        var host = new hostModel();

        const insertMany = await hostModel.insertMany(payload.data);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(insertMany,'','\t'));

        const saveMany = await hostModel.save();

        res.status(200).send('Ok');
    })();
});
```

That `console.log` shows me the records but when I do `hostModel.save()` I get `hostModel.save is not a function`.

How can I save the inserted docs?

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: please use that link you can find the detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697448/mongodb-mongoose-insert-is-not-a-function/68662249#68662249

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to create instance `new hostModel()` here... use directly `hostModel` and also no need to `save()` as well because insert many itself creates the collections... and make sure `payload.data` has array of objects

```
router.post('/host', function (req, res, next) {
  const array = [{hostname: 'hostname', timestamp: 'timestamp'},
                 {hostname: 'hostname', timestamp: 'timestamp'}]

    var payload = req.body;

    (async function(){

        const insertMany = await hostModel.insertMany(array);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(insertMany,'','\t'));

        res.status(200).send('Ok');
    })();
});
```

Comment: I tried that but I still don't get the docs saved to the collection. According to Mongoose docs insertMany does not trigger save middleware. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: this is my data array "data": [
    {
        "hostname": "localhost",
        "timestamp": 1527668059689
    }
] Obviously it contains more than one item... just posted this as an example.

Comment: Still the same result with the hard coded items... none saved.

Comment: This is the result for console.log(insertMany): [
 {
  "_id": "5b0e5e95b5f6844c5a8d5f02",
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "timestamp": 1527668059689,
  "__v": 0
 },
 {
  "_id": "5b0e5e95b5f6844c5a8d5f03",
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "timestamp": 1527668059789,
  "__v": 0
 }
]. It gets the ids returned... kinda weird to not be saved.

Comment: Hi @Marrone, I'm facing a similar issue. Were you able to fix this?

Comment: Hi @Lizzy, please, check my answer. I've moved to the updateMany using the "criteria"

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the same issue. I've solved it using the `updateMany` with `criteria` as follows:

```
router.post('/heatmap', function (req, res, next) {
    let payload = req.body;

   (async function(){

        let heatmapDate = new Date(payload[0].heatmapdata[0].timestamp).toISOString().substring(0, 10);

        payload[0].heatmapDate = heatmapDate;

        let sessionData = payload[0];

        sessionData.sessionrecordheatmap = payload[0].heatmapdata;

        let criteriaSession = {
            sessionId:{ $eq: payload[0].sessionId}
        };

        const updatetManySession = await updateManySessionRecord(sessionrecordModel, criteriaSession, sessionData);

        res.status(200).send(updatetManyHeatmap);
    })();
});

async function updateManySessionRecord(schema, criteria, data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        schema.updateMany(criteria, 
            {
                id: data.id,
                clientIp: data.clientIp,
                device: data.device,
                heatmapDate: data.heatmapDate,
                protocol: data.protocol,
                hostname: data.hostname,
                pagePath: data.pagePath,
                pageImage: data.pageImage,
                pageTitle: data.pageTitle,
                clientHeight: data.clientHeight,
                clientWidth: data.clientWidth,
                $push: {
                    sessionrecordheatmap: data.sessionrecordheatmap,
                }
            },
            { 
                multi: true,
                upsert: true
            }, 
            function(err, res) {
                if (err) { 
                    console.log('ERROR - UPDATE MANY SESSIONRECORD: ' + err);
                    reject('insertFirst');
                } 
                else{ 
                    resolve('ok')
                }
            });
    });
}
```